# Edit prepended date format in error_log

Tags: php, error-logging

PHP 5.6

There's some way to define the format of the date shown when `error_log` is used?

I'm using it to log messages and errors from a certain script. It seems that `set_error_handler` [won't handle all error messages](http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php).

In some examples out there, people prepend the date with `date` directly on the arguments of `error_log`. Using that approach would led me to a repeated date string in my log file.

I want to output an ISO formatted local date time, but the date prepended on CLI (`php -f script.php`) and Apache that I get with

```
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'file.log');
error_log('Test');
```

Is something like this:

```
[14-Feb-2016 18:07:31 America/Mexico_City] Test
```

Noting that in most code examples the date format usually don't include the timezone. And that if I run it from the console I don't get the date prepended:

```
$ php -r 'error_log("Test");'
Test
```

Timezone is not set in either runtime or php.ini, but is correctly represented. I get this behavior on a [php5.6.18 package](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5-5.6/ubuntu) and a compiled from source php5.6.13. On the production server the script is being run through CLI, there's no apache installation.

### Solution

It seems that the date that is shown with error_log is not customizable.
Going forward with `set_error_handler` as suggested by @fusion3k I put together this error handler that will format the date, message and error levels with a more computer/human friendly format

```
// set_trigger_error only accepts E_USER_ constants values
define('ERROR', 256);   // Before E_USER_ERROR
define('INFO',  512);   // Before E_USER_WARNING
define('DEBUG', 1024);  // Before E_USER_NOTICE

function errorHandler ($errType, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine, $errContext) {
    $displayErrors = ini_get( 'display_errors' );
    $logErrors     = ini_get( 'log_errors' );
    $errorLog      = ini_get( 'error_log' );

    if( $displayErrors ) echo $errStr.PHP_EOL;

    if( $logErrors ) {
        $line = "";
        switch ($errType) {
            case DEBUG: 
                $type = 'DEBUG'; 
                break;
            case INFO: 
                $type = 'INFO'; 
                break;
            case ERROR: 
                $type = 'ERROR'; 
                $line = " (Line:".$errLine.")";
                break;
            default: 
                $type = 'WARN'; 
                $line = " (Line:".$errLine.")";
                break;
        }
        $message = date('Y-m-d H:i:sO').";".$type.";".$errStr.$line;
        file_put_contents($errorLog, $message.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}

set_error_handler('errorHandler');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'test.log');

trigger_error('Test', DEBUG);
```

Output

```
2016-02-15 14:20:05-0600;DEBUG;Test
```

Comment: Note: `LOG_INFO`, `LOG_DEBUG` and other similar constants are already defined for the `syslog` function. http://php.net/manual/es/function.syslog.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>If you use your **custom error log file,** you can simply prepend your preferred date format to log message.</del>

If you use standard **Apache log file,** you can't modify log format through php.

You have instead to modify entire Apache error log format in `httpd.conf` through `LogFormat` keyword: replace existent format with your desired format.

[Here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html) you can found complete syntax guide for `LogFormat`.

#### Edit:

After your last comment, I have searched through internet and I have performed some tests, then I realize that my previous answer is not correct: there is no way to modify `error_log()` behavior in php. In my case (I have Apache installed), `error_log()` function outputs Apache log format **even** on custom log file (defined through `ini_set('error_log')`).

In your case, I think that php use the OS log format (Are you sure that you don't have Apache installed, even if you don't use it?).

#### Alternative: trigger_error()

You can set your completely customizable error log format using `trigger_error()` — in conjunction with `set_error_handler()` — instead of `error_log()`:

```
function myErrorHandler( $errType, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine, $errContext )
{
    $displayErrors = ini_get( 'display_errors' );
    $logErrors     = ini_get( 'log_errors' );
    $errorLog      = ini_get( 'error_log' );

    if( $displayErrors ) echo $errStr.PHP_EOL;

    if( $logErrors )
    {
        $message = sprintf( '[%s] %s (%s, %s)', date('d-m H:i'), $errStr, $errFile, $errLine );
        file_put_contents( $errorLog, $message.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
    }
}

ini_set( 'log_errors', 1 );
ini_set( 'error_log', 'file.log' );

set_error_handler( 'myErrorHandler' );
trigger_error( 'Test' );
```

In the above example, `trigger_error` will append to *file.log* a line like this one:

```
[15-02 09:43] Test (Script/File/Path.php, 12)
```

Setting `error_handler` **all** system errors are processed by custom function. To simulate a system error, you have to use `trigger_error()` instead of `error_log()`.

To maximize customization, you can pass to `trigger_error` additional parameter `error_type`:

```
trigger_error( 'Test', E_WARNING );
```

will produce a *Warning level* error; default `error_type` value is `E_USER_NOTICE`. The error type is the first parameter (`$errType`) in custom function, so inside the custom error handler function you can modify the behavior depending of error type.

In my above simple example, the custom function also process some `ini` directives, so you can use `ini_set` in conjunction with `set_error_handler`. Please note that you can change the variables names of custom function parameters, but **not the order**, because this is defined by internal php error system.

If you decide to use `set_error_handler()`, read careful the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to understand the behavior and exceptions.

---

- Read more about [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)
- Read more about [trigger_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php)
- Read more about [error types](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)

Comment: The script is being run with `php -f file.php` in the production server. There's no even an installation of apache there. But more important, what do you mean by "custom error log file"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't have an apache installation. There's no httpd.conf in my system. And the `/etc/apache2/` has only one file: `conf.d/javascript-common.conf` being a symlink to `/etc/javascript-common/javascript-common.conf`. There's some scripts related to apache in `/usr/share/wwwconfig-common/`
I'm going to use a custom error handle. I just couldn't believe `error_log` wasn't editable

Comment: @Sdlion I forgot to check php.ini file: in my php.ini there are many error/log config, but nothing about log format. I say “Are you sure that you don't have Apache installed” because your date log format looks like my Apache error log format.

Comment: i think apache `ErrorLog` Directive wouldn't follow `LogFormat` since it (`LogFormat`) can be used by `CustomLog` Directive

Answer (score 2):

(I copied answer from @Sdlion into its own answer so we can vote on it)

It seems that the date that is shown with error_log is not customizable. Going forward with set_error_handler as suggested by @fusion3k I put together this error handler that will format the date, message and error levels with a more computer/human friendly format

```
// set_trigger_error only accepts E_USER_ constants values
define('ERROR', 256);   // Before E_USER_ERROR
define('INFO',  512);   // Before E_USER_WARNING
define('DEBUG', 1024);  // Before E_USER_NOTICE

function errorHandler ($errType, $errStr, $errFile, $errLine, $errContext) {
    $displayErrors = ini_get( 'display_errors' );
    $logErrors     = ini_get( 'log_errors' );
    $errorLog      = ini_get( 'error_log' );

    if( $displayErrors ) echo $errStr.PHP_EOL;

    if( $logErrors ) {
        $line = "";
        switch ($errType) {
            case DEBUG: 
                $type = 'DEBUG'; 
                break;
            case INFO: 
                $type = 'INFO'; 
                break;
            case ERROR: 
                $type = 'ERROR'; 
                $line = " (Line:".$errLine.")";
                break;
            default: 
                $type = 'WARN'; 
                $line = " (Line:".$errLine.")";
                break;
        }
        $message = date('Y-m-d H:i:sO').";".$type.";".$errStr.$line;
        file_put_contents($errorLog, $message.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    }
}

set_error_handler('errorHandler');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'test.log');

trigger_error('Test', DEBUG);
```

Output

```
2016-02-15 14:20:05-0600;DEBUG;Test
```